# Evaluate $\int [\cos(\csc^{-1}(\tan(\sec^{-1} (\cot(\sin^{-1}(\sec(\cot^{-1}(\csc(\cos^{-1}(x))))))))))]^2 dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I was trying to evaluate the below integral:

> $$\int \big[\cos(\csc^{-1}(\tan(\sec^{-1}(\cot(\sin^{-1}(\sec(\cot^{-1}(\csc(\cos^{-1}(x))))))))))\big]^2 dx$$

I managed to simplify it  to the below form:
$$\int \frac{3x^2-5}{2x^2-3}dx$$I then got to this form:
$$\frac{3x}{2}+C-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{2x^2-3}dx$$
I'm stuck at this point; could anyone show me how to proceed?

Comment: I checked it... you are a monster for composing so many functions!! XD

Comment: Take $3$ common in the denominator. And use the traditional trigonometric substitutions. (You can do $\sec\theta=x$)

Comment: If I may ask, how did you simplify, in a minute or two, the monster ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Inverse trigonometric function composed with trigonometric functions result in polynomials... these are fairly well known identites. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Compositions_of_trig_and_inverse_trig_functions)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen. I totally agree but doing it in less than two minutes by hand looks interesting !

Comment: @Claude simple application of a triangle and their ratios... repeated practice with these help in mental composition-decomposition.. but I'm still an amateur at integration...

Comment: @Kugelblitz. Good to know that ! I am totally unable to do that. Cheers :-)

Comment: @claude Please..you're capable of doing far greater things.

Comment: Thank you ! Being now an old man, there is one thing I know for sure : I know very very very little (less than $\epsilon$) !

Comment: Where did you find this exercise :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your simplification is correct (I didn't check), the final step would be handled like this:

$$\int\frac{1}{ax^2 - b}dx = \frac 1b \int\frac{1}{(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}x)^2 - 1}dx$$

At this point, you can factor the denominator into $(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}x + 1)(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}x - 1)$ and use partial fractions.

Alternatively, you could apply the substitution $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}x = \cosh y$ which would involve hyperbolic trig functions, if you're comfortable with that.

Comment: Yea thanks a lot! The hyperbolic function is slick; I managed to solve it myself using that before having seen this answer (browsed the net for an appropriate substitution.) Thanks.

Comment: @Kugelblitz Glad to help! :)